# Installing Latex on Android and animations

Tags: android

How do I use LaTeX on an Android device? Can I make animations using it? If yes, how? I am new to stuff like this. What are some good sources and app for using LaTeX on Android?

Comment: there have been apps but I would think most people use an online service such as overleaf rather than install locally on android

Comment: I use LaTeX on my Android device (Samsung tablet). Install the Termux app, which grants you a BASH shell. Then you can install TeXlive into Termux (using their method, not direct from TUG). As for animations, I know nothing about it, but I imagine it would also work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle provided better advice. I only have TeX on Android (via Termux app) because I also do other things with that. If I only needed TeX, it would be far more convenient to do it with an online service., because setting it up on Android requires a lot of downlooads, and expertise.

Comment: How do you do that?